# "What this thing was" vs "what was this thing"

Tags: expressions, writing-style

Example:

> What this *new plan* was I had no idea.
>
> What was this *new plan* I had no idea.

What's the difference between the two? Is one more common than the others?

Comment: No one says the latter. The former is usually written with a comma after *was*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What this new plan was, I had no idea.* This is a statement, and a common way to say this.

*"What was this new plan I had no idea."* This is a question ("What was this new plan?") fused to a statement ("I had no idea."). It will be understood by most - along with the assumption that it comes from a non-native speaker. (US)

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, the 1st sentence is correct. It is a form of indirect (a.k.a. reported) speech, where the inversion that occurred after a question-word in a direct question has to change back to statement word order.

In direct speech you would have a question (inversion occurs):

> A: "What is this new plan?"
>
> B: "I have no idea."

Now B speaks about this conversation, and has to use indirect speech (word order goes back to: subject group-verb group).

> I had no idea what this new plan was.

or

> What this new plan was, I had no idea.