# Order of words in a sentence

Tags: word-order, be

1. He raised my curiosity about what kind of person he is.
2. He raised my curiosity about what kind of person is he.

What is the right position of "is" in the sentence?

Comment: Related question, [“What this thing was” vs “what was this thing”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239438/what-this-thing-was-vs-what-was-this-thing).

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is the proper order. In this case, "what kind of person he is" is the noun phrase that defines the object of curiosity.

If you were asking a question about this person, you might say,

> "What kind of person is he?"

In this case, the verb comes first because it's a full interrogative sentence, and not just a descriptive phrase.

We could re-write number 2 to include the asking of a question:

> He raised my curiosity and made me ask myself, "What kind of person is
>   he?"